# Preventing the use of TypeScript 'interface-style' field initializers on a class

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here is `MyClass`:

```
export class MyClass {
    one: string;
    two: string;

    constructor(init?: Partial<MyClass>) {
        if (init) {
            Object.assign(this, init);
        } else {
            this.one = 'first';
            this.two = 'second';
        }
    }

    getOneAndTwo(): string {
        return `${this.one} and ${this.two}!`;
    }
}
```

Here are three ways to instantiate `MyClass`:

```
import { MyClass } from './models/my-class';

let mine = new MyClass();
console.log(mine.getOneAndTwo());

mine = new MyClass({
    one: 'One',
    two: 'Two'
});
console.log(mine.getOneAndTwo());

mine = {
    one: 'Three',
    two: 'Four'
} as MyClass;
console.log(mine.getOneAndTwo());
```

The last call to `getOneAndTwo()` will throw an error that starts off like this:

```
TypeError: mine.getOneAndTwo is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

I assume that the TypeScript compiler allows this to compile because it assumes I am treating a TypeScript class like a TypeScript interface. Is there any way I can throw a warning or an error to prevent this assumption from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything out of the box that would perform the checks you want.  From the [TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> **Type assertions**
>
> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” **A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data**. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. **TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.**

I suppose checks as to whether or not `mine` is of type `MyClass` could be done, but might not be the most practical of solutions IMO

```
let mine = new MyClass({
    one: 'One',
    two: 'Two'
});

console.log(mine instanceof MyClass); //true

mine = {
    one: 'Three',
    two: 'Four'
} as MyClass;

console.log(mine instanceof MyClass); // false
```